# Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js)

Tags: angular, npm, webpack, sass

I'm trying to run my angular 9 app on windows 10 but getting the following error while trying to serve it locally. Have a look at the error below:

> ERROR in ./src/assets/sass/pickandpay.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-3!./src/assets/sass/pickandpay.scss)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: Undefined variable: "$white-color".
> on line 99 of src/assets/sass/pickandpay/_base.scss
> from line 3 of H:\pick&pay_eCommerce\pickandpay-client\src\assets\sass\pickandpay.scss
> color: $white-color;
> ---------^

pickandpay.scss:

```css
// Core CSS

@import "pickandpay/base";
@import "pickandpay/blog-details";
@import "pickandpay/blog-sidebar";
@import "pickandpay/blog";
@import "pickandpay/breadcrumb";
@import "pickandpay/checkout";
@import "pickandpay/contact";
@import "pickandpay/footer";
@import "pickandpay/header";
@import "pickandpay/hero";
@import "pickandpay/home-page";
@import "pickandpay/mixins";
@import "pickandpay/responsive";
@import "pickandpay/shop-details";
@import "pickandpay/shop-grid";
@import "pickandpay/shoping-cart";
@import "pickandpay/sidebar";
@import "pickandpay/variable";
@import "pickandpay/style.scss";
```

_base.scss:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0;
  color: #111111;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

p {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Cairo', sans-serif;
  color: #6f6f6f;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

input:focus,
select:focus,
button:focus,
textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
  color: $white-color;
}

ul,
ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/*---------------------
  Helper CSS
-----------------------*/
.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: center;

  h2 {
    color: $normal-color;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;

    &:after {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      bottom: -15px;
      right: 0;
      height: 4px;
      width: 80px;
      background: $primary-color;
      content: "";
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
}

.set-bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top center;
}

.spad {
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.text-white h1,
.text-white h2,
.text-white h3,
.text-white h4,
.text-white h5,
.text-white h6,
.text-white p,
.text-white span,
.text-white li,
.text-white a {
  color: #fff;
}

/* buttons */
.primary-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px 28px 10px;
  color: $white-color;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: $primary-color;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.site-btn {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: $white-color;
  font-weight: 800;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 13px 30px 12px;
  background: $primary-color;
  border: none;
}

/* Preloder */
#preloder {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 999999;
  background: #000;
}

.loader {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -13px;
  margin-left: -13px;
  border-radius: 60px;
  animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: loader 0.8s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border: 4px solid #673ab7;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }

  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    border: 4px solid #673ab7;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    border: 4px solid #f44336;
    border-left-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

I tried googling it and do everything about it but didn't find any solution.

node -v12.16.1

Angular CLI version 9.1.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you have not defined the variable `$white-color`. If you want more in depth help it would help if you provided the `pickandpay.scss` file.

Comment: did it..have a look now

Comment: It seems like `$white-color` is indeed not defined in your current file. You could either define it in this file or remove the references to it.

Answer (score 2):

this is issues is caused because of the bootstrap conflicting.